# WebLogic 12c upgrade error: Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, weblogic, jax-ws

I upgraded from Weblogic 10.3.5 to 12c (12.1.2.0.0), and got this error on JAX-WS in an EJB which is in an EAR (Maven Spring Application): (I replaced actual application/package names to 'x').  We're not using JSP.

```
Error encountered during prepare phase of deploying WebService module 'X-SNAPSHOT.jar'. Unable to deploy EJB: X_PortTypeWS from X_PortTypeWS: [HTTP:101371]There was a failure when processing annotations for application /opt/oracle_12c/middleware/user_projects/domains/xs_domain/servers/x_ManagedServer_3/tmp/_WL_user/x-SNAPSHOT/p4yc6b. Ensure that the annotations are valid. The error is org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag
```

The following is the Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] x.x.x1:x1_ea:ear:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- x.x.x1:x1_core:ejb:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- x.x.x2:x2-core:jar:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xom:xom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- x.x.x2:x2-bpm:jar:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- x.x.x2:x2-http:jar:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxmail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- jaxx.ws.rs:jaxx.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0-m10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.hibernate.jaxx.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- x.x.x2:x2-jms:jar:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxx.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-xlidator:commons-xlidator:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-base:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- ca.uhn.hapi:hapi-structures-v24:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RC2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.0ea8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- jaxssist:jaxssist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:2.0.0-M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- jaxx.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- jaxx.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-atom-abdera:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-parser:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-i18n:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-actixtion_1.0.2_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.6:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-json:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-server:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- jaxx.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-main:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-client:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.abdera:abdera-extensions-html:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- nu.xlidator.htmlparser:htmlparser:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-atom:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- rome:rome:jar:0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jaxx.inject:jaxx.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.1.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- x.x.x2:x2-test:jar:4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    +- org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.3.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO]    +- xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- x.hhs.healthit.nhin.connect:common-types:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    +- eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:soapui:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jaxx.actixtion:actixtion:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jaxx.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2-fixed:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-ssl:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.11:compile
[INFO]    |  +- json:json-lib:jar:2.2.2-jdk15:compile
[INFO]    |  +- ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- swingx:swingx:jar:soapui:compile
[INFO]    |  +- groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jetty:servlet-api:jar:2.5-20081211:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net-components:netcomponents:jar:1.3.8a:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xmlbeans:xbean:jar:fixed-2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xmlbeans:xbean_xpath:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xmlbeans:xmlpublic:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xmlbeans:jsr173:jar:xmlbeans-2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:soapui-xmlbeans:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:policy-xmlbeans:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:soap-xmlbeans:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:wadl-xmlbeans:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:j2ee-xmlbeans:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- eviware:ext-xmlbeans:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8j:compile
[INFO]    |  +- saxon:saxon-dom:jar:9.1.0.8j:compile
[INFO]    |  +- xml-security:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- opensaml:opensaml:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- wss4j:wss4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
[INFO]    |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:144:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jtidy:jtidy:jar:r872-jdk15:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jaxx.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- hermesjms:hermes:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  +- amf:flex-messaging-common:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- amf:flex-messaging-core:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- amf:flex-messaging-opt:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- amf:flex-messaging-proxy:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- amf:flex-messaging-remoting:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- thoughtworks:xstream:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.7:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:jar:1.9.14:compile
[INFO]    |  +- fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.2.9:compile
[INFO]    \- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0.6.0:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The jars in the target lib directory:

```
Lib directory:
rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   59163 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-client-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  156561 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-core-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   15470 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-extensions-html-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   26487 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-extensions-json-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   25378 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-extensions-main-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  610504 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-i18n-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  141586 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-parser-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  157988 Jun 23 19:14 abdera-server-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   69409 Jun 23 19:14 actixtion-1.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  546498 Jun 23 19:14 antlr-3.0ea8.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev    4467 Jun 23 19:14 aopalliance-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   43581 Jun 23 19:14 asm-3.3.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 8252251 Jun 23 19:14 aspectjtools-1.5.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  140953 Jun 23 19:14 axiom-api-1.2.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  116719 Jun 23 19:14 axiom-impl-1.2.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1643601 Jun 23 19:14 bcprov-jdk15-144.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  287192 Jun 23 19:14 cglib-2.2.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  188671 Jun 23 19:14 commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   30117 Jun 23 19:14 commons-cli-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  232771 Jun 23 19:14 commons-codec-1.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  575389 Jun 23 19:14 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  168446 Jun 23 19:14 commons-digester-1.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  305001 Jun 23 19:14 commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  159509 Jun 23 19:14 commons-io-2.0.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  279193 Jun 23 19:14 commons-lang-2.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  315805 Jun 23 19:14 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   60686 Jun 23 19:14 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  138956 Jun 23 19:14 commons-xlidator-1.3.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 8298368 Jun 23 19:14 common-types-2.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  253950 Jun 23 19:14 cssparser-0.9.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1089367 Jun 23 19:14 cxf-api-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   38694 Jun 23 19:14 cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  407248 Jun 23 19:14 cxf-rt-core-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  636458 Jun 23 19:14 cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  255839 Jun 23 19:14 cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  313898 Jun 23 19:14 dom4j-1.6.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  239490 Jun 23 19:14 dozer-5.3.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  497537 Jun 23 19:14 ext-xmlbeans-1.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   86463 Jun 23 19:14 ezmorph-1.0.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   86487 Jun 23 19:14 ezmorph-1.0.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   89768 Jun 23 19:14 flex-messaging-common-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  644264 Jun 23 19:14 flex-messaging-core-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   20969 Jun 23 19:14 flex-messaging-opt-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   66076 Jun 23 19:14 flex-messaging-proxy-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   18822 Jun 23 19:14 flex-messaging-remoting-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   33528 Jun 23 19:14 geronimo-actixtion_1.0.2_spec-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  223298 Jun 23 19:14 geronimo-jaxmail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   28804 Jun 23 19:14 geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 5956302 Jun 23 19:14 groovy-all-1.8.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  710492 Jun 23 19:14 guice-3.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   65012 Jun 23 19:14 guice-servlet-3.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  446970 Jun 23 19:14 hapi-base-0.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1642549 Jun 23 19:14 hapi-structures-v24-0.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1350400 Jun 23 19:14 hermes-1.14.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   71283 Jun 23 19:14 hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 3123360 Jun 23 19:14 hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  426671 Jun 23 19:14 hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.10.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  102661 Jun 23 19:14 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  135800 Jun 23 19:14 htmlparser-1.0.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  910727 Jun 23 19:14 htmlunit-core-js-2.7.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  351132 Jun 23 19:14 httpclient-4.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  105864 Jun 23 19:14 httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  181204 Jun 23 19:14 httpcore-4.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  196368 Jun 23 19:14 httpcore-nio-4.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   26889 Jun 23 19:14 httpmime-4.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   67061 Jun 23 19:14 x2-bpm-4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  210643 Jun 23 19:14 x2-core-4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   88215 Jun 23 19:14 x2-http-4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   41939 Jun 23 19:14 x2-jms-4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   57464 Jun 23 19:14 x2-test-4.4.1.115-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1083442 Jun 23 19:14 j2ee-xmlbeans-1.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  228286 Jun 23 19:14 jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   18323 Jun 23 19:14 jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  765648 Jun 23 19:14 jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   27075 Jun 23 19:14 jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  644148 Jun 23 19:14 jaxssist-3.12.1.GA.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev    2497 Jun 23 19:14 jaxx.inject-1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  110928 Jun 23 19:14 jaxx.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  105134 Jun 23 19:14 jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  890168 Jun 23 19:14 jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  231882 Jun 23 19:14 jaxen-1.1.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  267848 Jun 23 19:14 jcifs-1.2.9.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  153253 Jun 23 19:14 jdom-1.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  153115 Jun 23 19:14 jdom-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   12768 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-atom-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   19787 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-atom-abdera-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  133906 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-client-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  479324 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-core-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   16157 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-guice-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  165342 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-json-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   53250 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-multipart-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  684202 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-server-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  127134 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-servlet-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   17357 Jun 23 19:14 jersey-spring-1.18.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   67758 Jun 23 19:14 jettison-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  539912 Jun 23 19:14 jetty-6.1.26.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  177131 Jun 23 19:14 jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   26257 Jun 23 19:14 jms-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  871260 Jun 23 19:14 js-1.7R2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  143977 Jun 23 19:14 json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  151839 Jun 23 19:14 json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   23630 Jun 23 19:14 jsr173-xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   15071 Jun 23 19:14 jta-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  279220 Jun 23 19:14 jtidy-r872-jdk15.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   31906 Jun 23 19:14 jug-2.0.0-asl.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  481535 Jun 23 19:14 log4j-1.2.16.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  388864 Jun 23 19:14 mail-1.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   10133 Jun 23 19:14 maven-plugin-api-2.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   17541 Jun 23 19:14 maven-soapui-plugin-4.5.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   62135 Jun 23 19:14 mimepull-1.9.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  124361 Jun 23 19:14 nekohtml-1.9.14.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   92484 Jun 23 19:14 netcomponents-1.3.8a.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  271267 Jun 23 19:14 not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  155714 Jun 23 19:14 opensaml-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  656311 Jun 23 19:14 policy-xmlbeans-1.5.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  208025 Jun 23 19:14 rome-0.9.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  535273 Jun 23 19:14 rsyntaxtextarea-1.3.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  427559 Jun 23 19:14 saaj-impl-1.3.19.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   15808 Jun 23 19:14 sac-1.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 5046534 Jun 23 19:14 saxon-9.1.0.8.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 5046534 Jun 23 19:14 saxon-9.1.0.8j.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  129236 Jun 23 19:14 saxon-dom-9.1.0.8.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  129236 Jun 23 19:14 saxon-dom-9.1.0.8j.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  278281 Jun 23 19:14 serializer-2.7.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   97693 Jun 23 19:14 servlet-api-2.4.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  134133 Jun 23 19:14 servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   26176 Jun 23 19:14 slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev    9711 Jun 23 19:14 slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 5873359 Jun 23 19:14 soapui-4.5.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1380777 Jun 23 19:14 soapui-xmlbeans-4.5.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  177958 Jun 23 19:14 soap-xmlbeans-1.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  321190 Jun 23 19:14 spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   53082 Jun 23 19:14 spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  555410 Jun 23 19:14 spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  668861 Jun 23 19:14 spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  100870 Jun 23 19:14 spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  382442 Jun 23 19:14 spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  169752 Jun 23 19:14 spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  385712 Jun 23 19:14 spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  185312 Jun 23 19:14 spring-jms-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  334327 Jun 23 19:14 spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   61379 Jun 23 19:14 spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  340643 Jun 23 19:14 spring-security-core-3.1.0.RC2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  231922 Jun 23 19:14 spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  395587 Jun 23 19:14 spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  809013 Jun 23 19:14 spring-ws-2.0.0-M1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  182112 Jun 23 19:14 stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev   23346 Jun 23 19:14 stax-api-1.0-2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1156443 Jun 23 19:14 swingx-soapui.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  206074 Jun 23 19:14 wadl-xmlbeans-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  482245 Jun 23 19:14 woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  145963 Jun 23 19:14 wsdl4j-1.6.2-fixed.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  323799 Jun 23 19:14 wss4j-1.5.8.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  520389 Jun 23 19:14 wstx-asl-3.2.6.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 3176148 Jun 23 19:14 xalan-2.7.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 2695335 Jun 23 19:14 xbean-fixed-2.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev    6489 Jun 23 19:14 xbean_xpath-2.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev 1367760 Jun 23 19:14 xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  220536 Jun 23 19:14 xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  124724 Jun 23 19:14 xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  432377 Jun 23 19:14 xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  162818 Jun 23 19:14 xmlschema-core-2.0.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  447633 Jun 23 19:14 xmlsec-1.4.3.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  431568 Jun 23 19:14 xom-1.1.jar
-rw-rw-r--. 1 dev dev  431406 Jun 23 19:14 xstream-1.3.1.jar
```

In our web service class we use the following annotations:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(portName = "X_PortType", serviceName = "XService", endpointInterface = "X.XPortType")
@Addressing(enabled = true)
@HandlerChain(file = "xca_handler.xml")
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class X_PortTypeWS implements
        X.XType {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory
            .getLog(X_PortTypeWS.class);

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext context;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "XComponent")
    Component<Object, Object> xComponent;

    @Override
    @WebMethod(operationName = "X-bResponse", action = "tns:X-bResponse")
    @WebResult(name = "Acknowledgement", targetNamespace = "urn:x:x", partName = "body")
    public AcknowledgementType xResponse(
            @WebParam(name = "RegistryResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:x:x:3.0", partName = "body") XResponseType xResponse) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have jstl.jar nor standard.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: we didn't have that before either in WL 10.3.5.  Is this something that is required now in 12c?

Comment: you were right. That was the issue.  Maybe the old version of WebLogic had these libraries already.